# Anyone know if this kind of Polyethylene is safe to use?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm planning to make a weighted blanket and I've looked around the internet and most people use poly pellets or glass beads for the weight.

Glass beads is kinda hard to find in where I live, so I went with poly pellets. I realize that there are many type of poly such as PE, PP, HDPE, etc.

I ended up buying 4 pounds of [these](https://preview.ibb.co/kX4oz8/IMG_20180709_140726_HDR.jpg), I asked the seller and he said it's PE so I'm wondering if these are safe to use? Because the smell is quiet strong (smells like oil to me). They have a white transparent version but it costs more, this only costs 1/3 compared to the white transparent version.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: We really don't have enough information to provide useful answers here. Many types of polyethylene are used safely for consumer products, including food storage containers, but if nothing else, the strong smell will make whatever you've got undesirable. It may be possible to wash the beads with some solvent, but without knowing the grade of plastic or what they may be contaminated with, it will be hard to give any answer about how suitable they are for your use.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend a petroleum-based product anywhere near an area you are going to sleep in - full stop as it were. The main use of many of these products seems to be to help get a barbecue going. Try a craft site or 
veterinary supplier for bulk supplies of plastic pellets? And good luck with the blanket.